# Incorrect redirect with react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

the react.js code below allows you to view a table with the component present in the table.js file this allows you to view a table and have access saved in it, to view the data you need to click on the button of each row that is generated in the table, when the user clicks the new EditClient component present at the route `/app/editclient` must be displayed, now when I execute the call to the endpoint `/app/editclient` with this react-router configuration the redirect is made to here,
the function that modifies the displayed router is: getEventEditUser

**/app/editclient --> /app/editclient#/app/main/dashboard**

now how can i fix this? because the path is wrong

**Layout.js**

```
<TransitionGroup>
                <CSSTransition
                  key={this.props.location.key}
                  classNames="fade"
                  timeout={200}
                >
                  <Switch>
                    <Route path="/app/main" exact render={() => <Redirect to="/app/main/dashboard" />} />
                    <Route path="/app/main/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
                    <Route path="/app/icons" exact component={UIIcons} />
                    <Route path="/app/notifications" exact component={UINotifications} />
                    <Route path="/app/charts" exact component={Charts} />
                    <Route path="/app/tables" exact component={TablesStatic} />
                    <Route path="/app/maps" exact component={MapsGoogle} />
                    <Route path="/app/typography" exact component={CoreTypography} />
                    <Route path="/app/editclient" exact component={EditClient} />
                  </Switch>
                </CSSTransition>
              </TransitionGroup>
```

**Table.js:**

```
class Static extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.textInput = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      tableStyles: [
      ],

    };

    this.checkAll = this.checkAll.bind(this);
  }

  parseDate(date) {
    this.dateSet = date.toDateString().split(" ");

    return `${date.toLocaleString("en-us", { month: "long" })} ${
      this.dateSet[2]
    }, ${this.dateSet[3]}`;
  }

  checkAll(ev, checkbox) {
    const checkboxArr = new Array(this.state[checkbox].length).fill(
      ev.target.checked
    );
    this.setState({
      [checkbox]: checkboxArr,
    });
  }

  //Function create user
  async newuser(event){
    let ragionesocialetext = event.target.value;
    console.log("Ragione Sociale: "+ragionesocialetext);
  }

  getEventEditUser(id){
    window.open("/app/editclient");
    console.log("Identificativo: "+id);
  }

  //Function call con text change
  async handleChange(event) {
    let searchtext = event.target.value;
    var result=await ricercaclienti(searchtext);
    var results=[];
    for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
      var value={
        id: result[i].IdCliente,
        picture: require("../../../images/cliente.jpg"), // eslint-disable-line global-require
        description: result[i].RagioneSociale,
        info: {
          citta: result[i].Citta,
          provincia: result[i].Provincia,
        },
        DataInserimento: result[i].DataInserimento,
        Cap: result[i].Cap,
        progress: {
          percent: 30,
          colorClass: "warning",
        }
      };
      results.push(value);
    }
    this.setState({tableStyles: results});
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className={s.root}>
        <h2 className="page-title">
          Clienti - <span className="fw-semi-bold"> Anagrafia</span>
        </h2>
        <Row>
          <Col>

            <Widget

              settings
              close
              bodyClass={s.mainTableWidget}
            >
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>

            <FormGroup >
            <InputGroup className="input-group-no-border">
              <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                <InputGroupText>
                  <i className="fa fa-search text-white" />
                </InputGroupText>
              </InputGroupAddon>
              <Input
                id="search-input"
                className="input-transparent"
                placeholder="Ricerca"
                type='text'
  name='ricerca'
  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
              />
            </InputGroup>
          </FormGroup>
              <Table striped>
                <thead>
                  <tr className="fs-sm">
                    <th className="hidden-sm-down">#</th>
                    <th>Cliente</th>
                    <th>Ragione Sociale</th>
                    <th className="hidden-sm-down">Indirizzo</th>
                    <th className="hidden-sm-down">Data Inserimento</th>
                    <th className="hidden-sm-down">CAP</th>
                    <th className="hidden-sm-down">Edit</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {this.state.tableStyles.map((row) => (
                    
                    <tr key={row.id}  >
                      <td>{row.id}</td>
                      <td>
                        <img
                          className="img-rounded"
                          src={row.picture}
                          alt=""
                          height="50"
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {row.description}
                        {row.label && (
                          <div>
                            <Badge color={row.label.colorClass}>
                              {row.label.text}
                            </Badge>
                          </div>
                        )}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <p className="mb-0">
                          <small>
                            Città:
                            <span className="text-muted fw-semi-bold">
                              &nbsp; {row.info.citta}
                            </span>
                          </small>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <small>
                            Provincia:
                            <span className="text-muted fw-semi-bold">
                              &nbsp; {row.info.provincia}
                            </span>
                          </small>
                        </p>
                      </td>
                      <td className="text-muted">{row.DataInserimento}</td>
                      <td className="text-muted">{row.Cap}</td>
                      <td className="width-150">
                        <Button color="default" className="mr-2" size="sm" onClick={() => this.getEventEditUser(row.id)}>
                    Modifica
                  </Button>
                        
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </Table>
              <div className="clearfix">
                <div className="float-right">
                  <Button color="default" className="mr-2" size="sm">
                    Refresh...
                  </Button>
                  <UncontrolledButtonDropdown>
                    <DropdownToggle
                      color="inverse"
                      className="mr-xs"
                      size="sm"
                      caret
                    >
                      Nuovo Cliente
                    </DropdownToggle>
                    <DropdownMenu>
                      <DropdownItem>Inserisci ragione sociale</DropdownItem>
                      <Input
                id="search-input"
                className="input-transparent"
                placeholder="ragionesociale"
                type='text'
  name='ragionesociale'
  onChange={this.newuser.bind(this)}
              />

                    </DropdownMenu>
                  </UncontrolledButtonDropdown>
                </div>
                <p></p>
              </div>
            </Widget>
          </Col>
        </Row>

                          </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Static;
```

Comment: ```getEventEditUser(id){
    //window.open("/app/editclient");
    history.push({path="/app/editclient", state:id})
    console.log("Identificativo: "+id);
  }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `react-router` you can also use utils function to navigate.
https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Router/history-object

To have access to the history object, you can either use hook `useHistory` or HOC `withRouter`.
Because you are using React class component, you have to use `withRouter`.

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

   navigate = () => {
     const { history } = this.props
     history.push('/hello')
   }
   
   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <button onClick={this.navigate}></button>
       </div>
    )
  } 
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent)
```